# How to create XML < XmlElement >= <other/></XmlElement >

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create the following XML. I'm usng System.Xml, C# with VisualStudio. The part I'm having trouble with is in the first line below. Getting the ">=" part. Pair apparently isn't a child of StyleMap. This is from a GoogleEarth KML file.

```
<StyleMap id="msn_placemark_circle"> = 
    <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#sn_placemark_circle</styleUrl>
    </Pair>
    <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#sh_placemark_circle_highlight</styleUrl>
    </Pair>
</StyleMap>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: The `=` is not part of the content, or at least it shouldn't be in there in your XML document.

Comment: It is better to use .Net Framework **LINQ to XML** API, `XElement` or `XDocument` data types.

Comment: @Progman "The = is not part of the content, or at least it shouldn't be in there in your XML documen"  - can you please clarify if you mean "GoogleEarth KML format does not have `=` at that spot"? (Obviously it is perfectly valid XML as-is, so some clarification of the comment would be nice).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `>=` or `> =` syntax in XML. "=" is just a regular character outside XML markup. For example:

```
<Tag>=</Tag>
```

is just a tag containing "=" character. What you see might be a typo, or it might be a text content mixed with other XML tags like this:

```
<Tag> =
  <OtherTag></OtherTag>
</Tag>
```

So, in that case the node tree looks like this:

```
-- parentNode
     +-- element: Tag
           +-- text: " ="
           +-- element: OtherTag
```

Comment: You may want to clarify that this type of node mix called "mixed content" (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content, https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xml-in-a/0596007647/ch03s02s07.html)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the links, I edited the wording slightly to emphasize the content being mixed.

Comment: Note that "mixed content" is a specific term (which is important when one wants to find a solution) and not just two words together (even if it actually means "text content mixed with other XML tags")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, I know, but I don't think it's relevant in OP's case. I thought it might be more confusing to digress to focus on that detail. Yor comment is still here to clarify this, so, I don't think more editing is necessary. Thanks!